# How to check readline input value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, readline

I'm trying to validate user input value using `nodejs` `readline`module whether the user input value is valid or `undefined`.
So far code is

```
const readline = require('readline')

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
})

rl.question("Enter User Name: ", (answer) => {
  answer === 'undefined' ? console.log("Plz Enetr value") : console.log(`${answer}`)  
  rl.close();
})
```

Comment: What is your question: you show a code example. Is the code example not working? What do you expect, and what happens instead? Please work on the question to make it more answerable.

Comment: The question is how do I validate user input's in CLI application. In this scenario what if the user hits enter without giving value ? what it will return ?? nothing so is that nothing is `null`, `undefined` ?

Comment: @SanjayShr I was looking for the same implementation to catch an empty output or to check if a user hit enter. There is an event listener `SIGNIT` on the interface as referenced [here](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#:~:text=there%20is%20no-,%27SIGINT%27,-event%20listener%20registered). This will allow you to handle those cases where a user just exit so sudden by hitting CTRL+C or CTRL+D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callback function, you could add

```
console.log('answer: ' + JSON.stringify(answer));
```

This will show

```
answer: ""
```

When the input is null. So change your code to

```
answer === '' ? console.log("Plz Enetr value") : console.log(`${answer}`)
```

To fix it.